# Chainer - Python - Logistic Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, logistic-regression, chainer

I created a simple Logistic Regression model using Python and Chainer but I am not fully satisfied with the end result. Therefore, I would like to get some help. One restriction: I would not like to interchange the implemented functionalities by already existing functionalities. I know that there are loss functions in Chainer which archieve almost the same, but a more complex model I am creating is using a custom loss function. The code is found here:

https://gist.github.com/kmjjacobs/62fc96ece695b47af8d667b060a64559

I would like to keep the model code as clean as possible, but as you can see, the **call** method is a forward to the loss method and I suspect there is a cleaner way to invoke the loss method in the training loop. I thought that it would be cleaner if the **call** method outputs the prediction and there is a seperate loss method for computing the loss. What are your thoughts on this?

I am also not sure on the converter function. Is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Do you have any remarks or best practices for writing Chainer code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first what is your main question? The best way to define loss function and predict function separately?

I looked your code, I think functionality of `init_scope` is different between `Link` and `Chain`. You cannot use it to register learnable parameter in Chain for this purpose. (Your current usage is for the `Link` and not for the `Chain`.)

- `init_scope` in `Link` is used to register parameter,
  https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/tutorial/function.html#links-that-wrap-functions
  https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/link.py#L197
- `init_scope` in `Chain` is used to register other `links`,
  https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/tutorial/basic.html#write-a-model-as-a-chain
  https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/link.py#L675

In your case, I think you can just use `chainer.links.Linear` to your `LogisticRegressionModel`, or you can define your own `Link` class which has the learnable parameter `W` and use this own `link` class in your `LogisticRegressionModel`.

Comment: Ah thank you. So if I understand it correctly, a Chain should be a collection of links (as a DAG) and links consists of collections of learnable parameters (but not other links)? And therefore you suggest to put the Linear link in the init_scope? My main question is what could be improved on the code and that has been answered now, thank you :-)!

Comment: Yes, I think so!
And I guess you already know it but `-t * F.log(y) - (1 - t) * F.log(1 - y)` can be replaced by `softmax` function and `1. / (1. + F.exp(-z))` can be replaced by `sigmoid` function. These function are optimized for this purpose, so when you consider performance seriously, it might be better to just use functions provided by chainer library.